# Data Testing with Hive

Tags: testing, hadoop, hive, hdfs

WE have Requirement in Our Project that Data Load from Source to HDFS Target Directory.

And we have to validate that data transformation (from source to Target) as/ Transformation rule.

They Gives us Flat Files of Source Tables (Single Flat file/Table) as well as of Target Table.

We have to do this data validation through Hive

How could we do that and is there any automation scope in this.

I am very beginner to this Hadoop technology. Kindly Help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below steps to validate data-

1- Write custom UDF and apply the validation rules over the rows, you might use REGEX for writing validation rules in UDF.

2- Write custom Serde or InputFOrmat to verify data while loading in Hive table.

3- Try Mapreduce Job to do the data validation directly.

---

If your source system is RDBMS then you can use Sqoop to import the data into HDFS or directly into Hive.

Sqoop has inbuilt functionality which validates the import/export using the row count and number of rows copied.
**sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/imdb --table movies --validate**

You can also create your own validation scheme by extending interfaces-
1-  ValidationThreshold.
2-  ValidationFailureHandler.
3-  Validator

```
example- 
 **sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/imdb \
--validate --validator org.apache.sqoop.validation.RowCountValidator \
--validation-threshold \
      org.apache.sqoop.validation.AbsoluteValidationThreshold \
--validation-failurehandler \
      org.apache.sqoop.validation.LogOnFailureHandler**
```

Comment: Client only provides us Flat files as a Source there is no database acess to QA & DEV both for that.

Comment: i would suggest you to go ahead with approach(1, 2 or 3) as there are no other ways to test the data.